# How can I have one function calling another function (as its argument)?

Tags: python

```
def GetAge():
   age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
   return age
  
    
def DetermineAge():
    if age < 2:
        print("Stage of Life: A Baby")
    elif age < 4:
        print("Stage of Life: A Toddler")
    elif age < 13:
        print("Stage of Life: A Kid")
    elif age < 20:
        print("Stage of Life: A Teenager")
    elif age < 65:
        print("Stage of Life: An Adult")
    elif age >= 65:
        print("Stage of Life: An Elder")
    else:
        print("Mistakes were made, please restart the program and try again.")

age = GetAge()
DetermineAge()
```

Trying to remove age out of age = GetAge how do I do that with my function? I already define age in my function and return it I only want my main code to say GetAge() and DetermineAge()

Comment: @DanielHao Not related.  The OP seems to want a global variable so they can call `GetAge()` then `DetermineAge()` but the current answer is the *right* way.

Answer (score 4):

Change `DetermineAge` to take `age` as an argument:

```
def DetermineAge(age):
    # rest of function is the same
```

and then the caller can pass the value as an argument directly instead of needing the variable `age` to be defined in the caller's own scope:

```
DetermineAge(GetAge())
```

Alternatively, you could have `DetermineAge` call `GetAge()` itself:

```
def DetermineAge():
    age = GetAge()
    # rest of function is the same
```

and then the caller can just do:

```
DetermineAge()
```

If you wanted the function itself to be an argument, you could also do that:

```
def DetermineAge(get_age_func):
    age = get_age_func()
    # rest of function is the same
```

```
DetermineAge(GetAge)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator function that takes a function as an argument and calls it with @, like this

```
def DetermineAge(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        age = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if age < 2:
            print("Stage of Life: A Baby")
        elif age < 4:
            print("Stage of Life: A Toddler")
        elif age < 13:
            print("Stage of Life: A Kid")
        elif age < 20:
            print("Stage of Life: A Teenager")
        elif age < 65:
            print("Stage of Life: An Adult")
        elif age >= 65:
            print("Stage of Life: An Elder")
        else:
            print("Mistakes were made, please restart the program and try again.")
        return age
    return wrapper


@DetermineAge
def GetAge():
    age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    return age


age = GetAge()
```